# Can I use socket.io with Play Framework 2.0 Web Sockets?

Tags: sockets, playframework, websocket, socket.io, playframework-2.0

There's a sample application that comes with Play Framework 2.0. The application uses Play's WebSocket implementation on the server side. I am wondering can I use socket.io on the client side to connect with Play's WebSocket implementation on the server side?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Websocket is still in draft. If both implementations of PlayFramework and socket.io follows similar protocol versions for websocket, it should be all right. Current protocol version: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17

Comment: Also echoing the previous comment, it's still early in the game with Websockets, but one developer at least is working on socket.io integration with Play 2.0 (in Scala though), but you can follow his sample app and see what it takes to get the integration going. https://github.com/rohit-tingendab/socket.io.play

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes, you can make Socket.io connect to your websocket server wia the corresponding ws url.

In practice, I tried and I had some issues, so it might require you to adapt Socket.io for it to work properly. Granted I tried on 2.0.1 or similar, so it may be working currently with no issues.

Comment: Connection wasn't working properly, couldn't establish at first then was failing randomly